# Progress Bar to Report status of AD Search

Tags: vb.net, active-directory

In a program I am working on, the user can search AD for a computer via a asset ID tag.  I have all of that working fine, but I am wondering if there is a way to show the progress of the search through a progress bar.

To do the search, I followed this code and mine is almost the exact same.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973834.aspx#dotnetadsearch_topic9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you used that whole example provided in the link and you are running the search on a background thread, add a progress bar named ProgressBar1 and try this:

Underneath the line:

```
Private Delegate Sub displayResult(ByVal textEntry As String)
```

Add this line:

```
Private Delegate Sub maxProgress(ByVal maxProgress As Integer)
```

Underneath these lines:

```
Public Event ResultFound(ByVal result As SearchResult)
Public Event SearchCompleted(ByVal entriesFound As Integer)
```

Add this line:

```
Public Event StartProgressBar(ByVal maxProgress As Integer)
```

Add the following code to the `StartSearch()` sub:

```
Dim queryResults As SearchResultCollection
RaiseEvent StartProgressBar(queryResults.Count)
```

Add the following procedures:

```
Private Sub StartProgress(ByVal maxProgress As Integer) Handles bkg.StartProgressBar
    Dim start as New maxProgress(AddressOf UpdateProgress)
    Me.Invoke(start, New Object() {maxProgress})
End Sub

Private Sub UpdateProgress(ByVal maxProgress as Integer)
    ProgressBar1.Maximum = maxProgress
    ProgressBar1.Step = 1
End Sub
```

and finally add this line to the `bkg_ResultFound` sub (outside of the `If` block)

```
ProgressBar1.PerformStep()
```